# Add temporary coredata entity in a relationship with a non-temporary entity

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Lets say i have a fetched result array filled with entities (Entity-A)

All these entities are in a relationship with another EntityB.

There might be some missing Entities in fetchedArray, in which case I want to manually create a new Entity-A, set it to a relationship with EntityB and add it to the entities array manually,

```
Doable, but I don't want to save those "created", "new" entities of A type.
```

If i do create a new Entity-A and add nil to its `NSManagedObjectContext`, i cannot add it as a relationship to entityB, cuz its in in the objectContext..

Is there another way here? i don't want to risk adding it to the db then deleting it cuz the apps connected via core data, and that would add a whole lot of complications, not to forget the unusual occurrences when the app just closes, battery running out or something..

My main question is a way to add the new Temporarity Entity in a relationship with the existing entity and forget about saving it..

any way out is really really appreciated, been struggling with this..

Answer (score 0):

jasonIM,

Yours is a perfect application for a scratchpad MOC (Managed Object Context). Basically, create a new MOC and never save it. Then items added to the entity never hit the persistent store.

Andrew

Comment: Caution, the newly created MOC with entities that want relationship with the existing MOC.. won't work. Relationships between different MOCs won't work.

Comment: Yes @adonoho i could create a  new MOC and never save it, But i wanted to have the entities in the new MOC to be related to entities in old MOC, which is not possible between two different contexts. I need to find a way to get these temp entities! that are related to existing entities and NOT be saves

Comment: jasonIM, Do not cross the MOCs, that would be bad. Why do you need cross MOC references instead of reading the old entities in from the persistent store via either fetches or object IDs? The row cache is your friend. Andrew

Comment: From a bunch of child entities, If particular one does not exist, i create it using a "nil" context. then have that related to .. like others.. to its parent entity. Coredata does not allow this kinda relationship. The reason for this attempt was, I could reference the child from the parent and when i do call MOC Save, the "nil" child entity that was created by me wouldn't have persisted. Though i can add an attribute and delete all child(s) with a "shouldDeleteBeforeSave".. but that would case a lot of overhead .. I hope you get what I'm trying to accomplish!

Comment: jasonIM/user134611, may I respectfully suggest that you are engaging in premature optimization. Do you actually have data from Instruments that shows you are creating performance critical overhead? From your comments, I doubt it. From my experience with Core Data, it is quite fast when it doesn't have to consult the persistent store. Objects that are created but never saved do not hit the store. I think you don't have a problem and I encourage you to try it the Core Data way. In general, don't fight the Cocoa frameworks. Andrew